# Can I use IJSRuntime *without* Blazor, for example in pure ASP.NET Core Razor pages?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages, blazor-server-side

I know that IJSRuntime implementation (in Blazor Server App) uses SignalR to communicate its client couterpart to execute the given JavaScript function.

**Question**

Is it possible to have this sole functionality (without reinventing the wheel and implementing it from scratch) in a pure ASP.NET Pages application? As far as I understand we must have a SignalR channel, a client side script, and the IJSRuntime implementation on server side. (without the Blazor SPA infra with all the rendering tricks)